# Why is $\operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j) \leq 1/\min(i,j)$?

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

I'm reading this proof and I understand everything except the step marked by an arrow where $\operatorname{cov}(x_i,x_j)< 1/\min(x_i,x_j)$.

[image]

I do not understand how they got that step directly and the consecutive step of getting that summation after.

Answer (score 1):

Check that 
$\max\big(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b})= \frac{1}{\min(a,b)}$

where $a$ and $b$
 are positive numbers

Comment: In the question earlier I proved cov(xi,xj) < max(pi,pj) 
I get that max(pi,pj) = 1/min(pi,pj)
How did it become just the indexes (i,j) and getting that summation after that is what I'm trying to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @rbeginner ... because we have, right at the beginning $p_n=1/n$. Therefore, the answer by Oliver Diaz is good.